# Understanding Fact Tables

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

Our group is looking to better understand our data and implement some best practices. After reading some of the guides on [codeproject on designing a data warehouse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652108/Create-First-Data-WareHouse), we realized we need to start with a basic understanding of dimension and fact tables, as it relates to our own data. We have gone back and forth on what constitutes a fact table. Below is an image of a portion of our database.
[image]

These tables sit below our operational system where details and attributes flow directly into the PO_Header, PO_Detail, Appointment_Detail, and Appointment_Header tables. There are a few true dimension tables for dates, locations, and other values. For example when an appointment is made, it is given a Appointment number for that particular country. Appointment numbers are unique only at the country level. That appointment has attributes at the appointment level and are created against specific Purchase Orders (POs).

**Our question is:** Are the Appointment and PO tables true "Fact" tables or some sort of hybrid fact/dimension? If the business requires a view across all tables, is joining these tables above as described the right approach? As this is the operational system, we don't have the ability to change the structure but can redesign the structure in our data warehouse if needed.

Comment: A PO-> Purchase Order, have updated the question with that clarification.

Comment: What is the process or event you are trying to analyze? That is your starting point

Comment: An example would be to provide a report of what POs are cancelled (PO_Header.Cancel_Flag) that will be delivering next week (Appointment_Header.Delivery_Dt).